# Use array in JSON configuration file in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

My serverless framework is trying to set an environment variable, CONFIG, to be contents of a JSON object.

My serverless.yml has this entry:

```
  environment:
    ${file(./config.json)}
```

and my config.json looks like this:

```
{
    "VARIABLE1": "value1",
    "VARIABLE2": "value2",
    "INT_VARIABLE": 3
    "BOOLEAN_TEST": true
}
```

This seems to work just fine.  ie:

`console.log(process.env.VARIABLE1)` outputs `value1`

`console.log(process.env.INT_VARIABLE)` outputs `3` (as a string... but I can convert if needed)

`console.log(process.env.BOOLEAN_TEST)` outputs `true` (as a string... but that's not the end of the world)

But when I go to add an array to the config.json, making the config.json look like this:

```
{
    "VARIABLE1": "value1",
    "VARIABLE2": "value2",
    "INT_VARIABLE": 3
    "BOOLEAN_TEST": true
    "ARRAY_TEST": ["arrVal1", "arrVal2", "arrVal3"]
}
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid configuration encountered   at
> 'provider.environment.ARRAY_TEST': unsupported configuration format

How can I add an array as a environmental variable in serverless framework? (same basic question about adding sub-objects)

Comment: same question here! Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: ok it seems this works with serverless v3

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can split the elements by a delimiter:

serverless.yml

```
environment:
     VARIABLE_1: ${file(./config.json):VARIABLE_1}
     ARRAY_TEST:
        "Fn::Split":
            - ","
            - ${file(./config.json):ARRAY_TEST}
```

config.json

```
{
    "VARIABLE_1": "value1",
    "ARRAY_TEST": "arrVal1,arrVal2,arrVal3"
}
```